# How to Change Background Image Based on User Input | HTML, CSS, JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, background

I have done a lot of research on how to do this, yet I can't seem to find a specific answer. I am trying to allow the user to input a file from their computer, and turn that file into the background of the webpage. My following code is shown below:

```
    <head>
        <script>
            function changeBackground() {
                var input = document.getElementById("background").value;
                localStorage.setItem("Background", input);
                var result = localStorage.getItem("Background");
                $('body').css({ 'background-image': "url(" + result + ")" });
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="background" type="file" onchange="changeBackground()">
    </body>
```

If someone could please explain to me what I need to do to get this to work, I would very much appreciate it. I already understand I need to use `localStorage` to make sure that the selected background is remembered, I am just having trouble getting the background to change. If there is already an article on how to do this, I would appreciate a link to it. Thanks!

**EDIT**

Nikhil and user6003859 explained to me why it isn't working. I guess I just need to figure out how to use Ajax and PHP to change it. If anyone has more advice on this, I would love to hear it. Thanks everyone for helping me solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modern browsers normally restrict access to the user's local files (in this case an image). What you're trying to do is display an image from the user's local filestorage, via the path you get from the `<input type='file' />` value.

What you should instead be doing, is uploading the image to your server (probably with ajax, so it feels seamless), and then displaying the file *from your server* on to your page.

**EDIT**: Even though this is kind of a new question, I'll give you an example on how to change an element's background based on a URL provided by the user:

```js
var inp = document.getElementById('inp');
var res = document.getElementById('res');

inp.oninput = function()
{
  res.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + inp.value + ')';
};
```

```css
div
{
  width: 5em;
  height: 5em;
}
```

```html
<input type='text' id='inp' />
<div id='res'>
</div>
```

Comment: Would you please explain how I could do this with some code? I am not very sure how to execute that.

Comment: What if I just let the user input the URL of an image? How would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

It's better practice to use file reader.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
             $("#file").change(function(){
                   var length=this.files.length;
                        if(!length){
                          return false;
                         }
                        changeBackground(this);
                });
       });
     
      // Creating the function
      function changeBackground(img){
            var file = img.files[0];
            var imagefile = file.type;
            var match= ["image/jpeg","image/png","image/jpg"];
                  if(!((imagefile==match[0]) || (imagefile==match[1]) || (imagefile==match[2]))){
                        alert("Invalid File Extension");
                  }else{
                        var reader = new FileReader();
                        reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
                        reader.readAsDataURL(img.files[0]);
                  }
            function imageIsLoaded(e) {
                  $('body').css({ 'background-image': "url(" + e.target.result + ")" });
           
                  }     
            }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="file" name="" id="file" value="Click">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried using your code. Is there something I need to change to fit my requirements? It isn't working for me.

Comment: Sorry for errors. I have edited the answer and added a working demo for you at my website http://code.whquery.com/?data=58a7e2181c7dc

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that purely with client-side because of security reasons.

The moment you upload say an image, the browser gives it a "fakepath" like so:

```
C:\fakepath\<filename>.png
```

> **This is a security implementation of the browser - the browser is protecting you from accessing your disk structure.**

Hence when you check the value of your input after uploading, you would get the above fakepath ie. `C:\fakepath\<filename>.png`. Using this as the background obviously would not work.

Usually to achieve this you need to first store it in a server, then fetch the value from the server and apply the background.

Answer (score 0):

To use a local file, store it in a blob

```
<head>
    <script>
        function changeBackground() {
            var backgroundFile = document.getElementById("background").files[0];
            $('body').css({ 'background-image': "url(" + URL.createObjectURL(backgroundFile) + ")" });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="background" type="file" onchange="changeBackground()">
</body>
```